# (Read more link) to modal fade view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to add modal fade in slideshow content(read more..)
when I but modal fade number 1 ("#portfolioModal(1)") in all of ==>

```html
 <button name="btn1" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal1">Read more</button></span>
```

it's work as I want.
But when I change the numbers to each #portfolioModal(1-6) as it correct
it doesn't work expect the first one.
Please help me :(

```html
<div class="container1">
        <div id="mySlides">
      <div id="slide1">
                <img src="images/slider1.jpg" alt="Slide 1 jFlow Plus"/>
              <span><b class="slideheading">Quality Managment</b><br/>ISO 9001...<button name="btn1" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal1">Read more</button></span>
     
            </div>
            <div id="slide2">
                <img src="images/slider2.jpg" alt="Slide 2 jFlow Plus"/>
               <span><b class="slideheading">Environment Managment</b><br/>ISO 14000....<button name="btn2" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal2">Read more</button></span>
      
            </div>
            <div id="slide3">
                <img src="images/slider3.jpg" alt="Slide 3 jFlow Plus"/>
               <span><b class="slideheading">Health and Safety Management </b><br/>OHSAS-18000...<button name="btn3" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal3">Read more</button></span>
 
            </div>
   <div id="slide4">
                <img src="images/slider4.jpg" alt="Slide 4 jFlow Plus"/>
               <span><b class="slideheading">Food Safety-HACCP</b><br/>ISO 22000...<button name="btn4" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal4">Read more</button></span>
            </div>
   <div id="slide5">
                <img src="images/slider5.jpg" alt="Slide 5 jFlow Plus"/>
               <span><b class="slideheading">Energy Management </b><br/>50001...<button name="btn5" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal5">Read more</button></span>
            </div>
   <div id="slide6">
                <img src="images/slider6.jpg" alt="Slide 6 jFlow Plus"/>
                <span><b class="slideheading">Medical devices Quality Managment</b><br/>13485...<button name="btn6" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal6">Read more</button></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="myController">
            <span class="jFlowControl"></span>
            <span class="jFlowControl"></span>
            <span class="jFlowControl"></span>
   <span class="jFlowControl"></span>
   <span class="jFlowControl"></span>
   <span class="jFlowControl"></span>
        </div>

        <section class="jFlowPrev">
            <div></div>
        </section>
        <section class="jFlowNext">
            <div></div>
        </section> 
  
  <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/slider/OHS.jpg" alt="">
    
 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close </button>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
      
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/slider/OHS.jpg" alt="">
    
 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close </button>
</div>
  
  
 </div>
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
      
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/slider/OHS.jpg" alt="">
    
 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close </button>
</div>
  
  
 </div>
 <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
      
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/slider/OHS.jpg" alt="">
    
 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close </button>
</div>
  
  
 </div>
 <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
      
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/slider/OHS.jpg" alt="">
    
 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close </button>
</div>
  
  
 </div>
 <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
      
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/slider/OHS.jpg" alt="">
    
 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close </button>
</div>
  
  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close some div's there, #portfolioModal2 must not be a child of #portfolioModal1.

https://jsfiddle.net/stby04/gyey79ar/

The HTML should look like this for every .portfolio-modal:

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
                <div class="rl">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/slider/OHS.jpg" alt="">


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```